# What was the first satellite built with mostly COTS electronics?

Tags: history, electronics, spaceflight-firsts, smallsat, cots

Computers and memory, radios, cameras, light sensors, temperature sensors, accelerometers & gyros<sup>1</sup>, power supplies, power conditioners and converters and battery interfaces can all be put together with [Commercial Off-The-Shelf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) or COTS components.

That doesn't necessarily meant they will work well together or individually in space.

**Question:** What was the first satellite built with mostly COTS electronics? How well did it work?

---

<sup>1</sup>MEMS accelerometers & gyros can be bought now but may not have been available when a potential answering-spacecraft was launched, so I've specified "*most* COTS electronics" above.

Comment: I've added the cubesat tag but I don't want to require a cubesat as an answer. [Do we need a smallsat tag, or might we just include small satellites within the cubesat tag's usage guidance?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1712/12102)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by COTS. Does the RAD6000 count as COTS? If one was designing a satellite in the early 2000s that would have been the go-to computer. Or by COTS do you mean a computer one can buy at a local computer store?

Comment: @DavidHammen references to COTS electronics in space are [all over the internet](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49777/how-to-know-in-which-quadrant-is-the-raan#comment161646_49777), it's not my construct and I don't think I should dare to redefine it. I would assume that [post 1996 RAD600s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RAD6000#History) might be a stretch at $200k. Answers to [How much more expensive are scientific instruments for space use?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27613/12102) use the term COTS at length, so it seems to have some generally understood meaning already.

Comment: I can't imagine anybody launching a spacecraft without having extensively tested whether or not its components will work well _together_. Of course, whether or not they will work well _in space_ is a different question.

Comment: When it comes to space-based equipment, I fear this will come close to opinions as to the meaning of "COTS" as it has evolved over time.  For example,  SpaceX's  "Starlink" satellites are practically COTS as an assembled unit.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft since this is an historical question and the answer will be *in the past*, it's not important what is seen as COTS today.

Comment: OK, then,  the Lacrosse series of spysats

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if they were COTS it would explain why they were so easily distracted! [Ashwat and the team manage to prepare the setup for the tests while distracting the Lacrosse satellite.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmanu:_The_Story_of_Pokhran) "actual video evidence" here: https://youtu.be/qN_9DnBh3hM?t=26 :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've just asked [I'd like to ask for a specific detail in the plot of a movie that I am not likely to be able to view, would that be that on-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4732/45856) in Movies SE meta.

Comment: I think this question is too vague without a specific definition of what you mean by COTS.

Comment: @CarlosN I will allow some flexibility based on what answers are (eventually) posted. The term COTS has been used in [65 posts](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=COTS) so far here, so clearly users here have something in mind when they use it. I'm not going to pre-define exactly what I want it to mean, but instead defer to the "experts" who so frequently use the term with a meaning in mind. In the mean time, I don't think it benefits the site by preventing users from posting answers.

Comment: @CarlosN I've just created a `cots` tag and added it to the clearest COTS questions. I think the term is sufficiently well defined for this community. No need to prevent answers here.

Comment: this is probably your starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMSAT

Answer (score 3):

I think the satellite is the [**Telstar 1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telstar_1) satellite

It was launched in July 1962

Telstar 1 was a communications satellite launched by NASA. It was the satellite that allowed the first live broadcast of television images between the United States and Europe.

It remained active for only 7 months, much shorter service life than today's artificial satellites. Although it no longer works, it is still in Earth orbit.

> A 53-meter terrestrial antenna manufactured by AT&T Corporation, located in Andover, Maine, was used for the transmissions between the U.S. and Europe. Built-in 1961, and used by Telstar 1, it was later used by Relay 1. Telstar 1 operated normally from launch until November 1962 when the radiation from the Starfish Prime detonation affected the command channel, which began to behave erratically. The satellite was continuously switched on to work around this problem. On November 23, 1962, the command channel stopped responding. On December 20, the satellite was successfully reactivated, and intermittent data were obtained until February 21, 1963, when the transmitter failed. The energy used by it was produced by 3,600 solar cells. The satellite relied on an active repeater and magnified signal strength by a factor of a hundred using a traveling wave tube amplifier (TWTA). Thirteen days after the launch, the first live broadcast of a television show between the United States and Europe took place

---

I found more about COTS and its history etc. on [this website](https://www.electronicproducts.com/a-brief-history-of-electronic-reliability-in-space-including-todays-risks-and-how-to-mitigate-them/)

Comment: Can you quote some of the passages from the site that support your belief that Telstar 1 was a COTS satellite or at least had COTS components? I can see COTS mentioned all over the place there, but answers should not rely on off-site material as part of the answer. Just quote a paragraph or several different sentences so that if/when the link rots/breaks your answer will still have value and be supported. *Thanks!*

Comment: I think you have found an excellent resource and have makings of a conclusive answer, but I can't accept or award the bounty unless it is more than a link-only answer as discussed above. I've lowered the bar a bit, from "nearly-all" to "mostly" if that helps.

Comment: Hey @uhoh I have updated my answer and I hope you'll check it out

Comment: [Can you quote some of the passages from the site that support your belief that Telstar 1 was a COTS satellite or at least had COTS components? I can see COTS mentioned all over the place there, but answers should not rely on off-site material as part of the answer. Just quote a paragraph or several different sentences so that if/when the link rots/breaks your answer will still have value and be supported. Thanks!*](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49800/51330?noredirect=1#comment168773_51330)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR Sputnik 1 / Explorer 1

Rationale: I believe the terms COTS and hi-rel have taken a while to take hold. If we take the assertions of the article linked to by RUNTIQ as correct then the significance is unstated but can be deduced from this sentence (end of 3rd para)

> Telstar had become the first “victim” of radiation-induced electronic
> failure. Six other satellites were lost within the next seven months,
> and the earnest study of radiation effects in electronics became a top
> priority for engineers and scientists the world over.

The apparent implication is that the concept of having specially selected parts of space missions, specifically with respect to radiation tolerance, did not exist at the time of the Telstar 1 launch.

So if that is the inference then why choose Telstar 1? Surely all satellites prior to that time used commercially available parts because no other concept existed at that time. You may note I've generalised away from any special modern definition of COTS to just "commercially available".  It might be better to say Explorer 1 rather than Sputnik 1 out of recognition that electronic parts in the Soviet Union may not have been considered "commercial" at all.

Obviously the concept of COTS has many dimensions, not limited just to radiation tolerance. However the twenty years prior to the Telstar 1 launch saw a great deal of evolution of transistor types and the idea of mass production hadn't been around for long. That all said, I'd be surprised if there wasn't already in existence a notion of procuring transistors of different quality, e.g. with respect to repeatable parameters and tolerance to high current and temperature.

Another aspect of this, which would help put an answer together, is when parts stress analysis began as a discipline, as this would very much inform the choice of component sources. My suspicion is this also began in the early '60s and I recall once seeing a paper on the topic dating from 1964 or so, though I can't find a link to it any more.

Answer (score 1):

From the information on these websites [1](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/23/sputniks-transmitter-beeps-again/), [2](https://soldersmoke.blogspot.com/2013/04/sputnik-schematic-found.html) & [3](https://www.pi4raz.nl/razzies/razzies201601.pdf) (sorry but 3 is in Dutch - the electronic schematic diagrams in 2 & 3 match), the radio transmitter for Sputnik 1 used electronic tubes/valves, capacitors, variable capacitors and resistors. All "readily" available electronic components in 1957.

It appears the tubes used in the radio transmitter where unusual,

> being a wire-ended design with all electrodes mounted on rods the length of the glass envelope. This design feature gave them a resistance to acceleration and vibration, making them suitable for use in aircraft, missiles, and rockets.

This gives the impression the tubes may have been military grade and not available for civilian purposes, unless they were available for use in civilian air craft.

Comment: This reminds me of my high school calculus teacher's warning about answering max/min questions; "Don't forget to check the endpoints!" Yes, I think that "...the first satellite built with mostly COTS electronics" is going to turn out to be  "...the first satellite built..." :-)

Comment: @uhoh: My understanding Sputnik 1 was very basic & it was a hurried design after Object D was rejected by Korolev apparently for being too heavy. With basic & hurried you get "what can we make out of what's available".